# Unknown publisher warning in application developed in VB.Net on Win7

Tags: vb.net

Hi
I have developed application using VB 2008 and develop a MSI setup for installation. 
Now problem is on windows 7 it generate a warning message on installation of software that "The publisher is unknown", but the software install well on continue of this warning.
When I run the software it did connect to Access database which is on installation directory, but it didn't allow to insert or update any data in the database. 
But when I run the software by right click on the EXE file "Run as a Administrator" then software works perfectly OK.
I add some information of signing certificate from the project explorer but not able to succeed.

Please help me out I am going crazy with this stuff....

Thanks

Answer (score 2):

The warining is just that - a warning. You can prevent it by buying a certificate and use that to sign the app.

You should not install a database or any other writable file in the application folder. A normal user has no Write privileges there. The certificate will make no difference.

You can use `Environment.GetFolderPath(Environment.SpecialFolder)` to find a more suitable location for the Db.

Comment: Just adding to the above answer, you can use the Environment.SpecialFolder's LocalApplicationData to get the directory and store the database file there.

Comment: Thanks for your reply but the problem is with the database security. It didn't allow to add any data in the database. And the setup install on the Program files.

Comment: The problem is windows x64 didn't allow user to insert record in the database. But if I run application as Administrator then program run full functionality.  And the setup which I created install software in the Program Files folder. Any suggestion ???....

Comment: Any suggestion? - Yes, read the answer again. Only an admin can open the Db in write-mode.